# Azure Could not create Static Web App (preview)

Tags: azure, azure-static-web-app

I am trying to add a static web app for the first time in Azure. I just signed up with a free account. I have a repository ready on GitHub and now I need to create the web app using the Azure Portal. These are the steps I've taken since signing in:

1. Navigated to Static Web Apps (Preview) page
2. Clicked "Add"

After I click Add, an error appears every time:
*Oops!
Could not create a Static Web App (preview)
Something went wrong while creating Static Web App (preview)*

Has anyone experienced this? Is this normal and I missed a step?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem this morning when I was creating a web app using App Service. I was using the Brave browser. **I tried it with the new Microsoft Edge browser and it worked flawlessly.** It might be due to **a cache problem**.

So my suggestions are:

- Clear the cache and try again
- Try it in another browser like the new Microsoft Edge or Firefox Mozilla.

Let me know if it helps!

Comment: I am using the new Microsoft Edge. I cleared the cache though, and it worked.